# Maneiras de verificar em tempo real se um objeto foi alterado

Tags: javascript

Estava procurando maneira de verificar se um objeto foi alterado.

Fiz no modo "gambiarra" usando `setInterval` para ficar verificando o tempo todo se foi alterado, mas não sei se seria uma boa maneira de verificar.

Como posso verificar se o objeto foi alterado de uma maneira mais simples ou mais eficiente?

```js
let obj = {
  item:"valor"
}

function ObjectListener(object, func){
  let savedObject = JSON.stringify(object);
  let listener = setInterval(onChange, 0);
  function onChange(){
    if(savedObject !== JSON.stringify(object)){
      savedObject = JSON.stringify(object)
      func();
      clearInterval(listener);
      listener = setInterval(onChange, 0);
    }
  }
}

new ObjectListener(obj, () => console.log("Alterado"));
```

```html
<h3>Digite um valor e clique em alterar</h3>
<input id="input">
<button onclick="obj.item = document.getElementById('input').value">Alterar</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar um [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), que [segundo a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

> *is used to define custom behavior for fundamental operations (e.g. property lookup, assignment, enumeration, function invocation, etc)*

Ou seja, é usado para definir um comportamento customizado para algumas operações fundamentais, entre elas a atribuição de um valor.

No caso, para atribuição de um valor ao objeto, basta definir no método [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set) um comportamento customizado para quando uma propriedade for alterada:

```js
let obj = {
  item:"valor"
}

obj = new Proxy(obj, {
  set: function (target, chave, valor) {
      console.log(`${chave} alterado para: ${valor}`);
      target[chave] = valor;
      return true;
  }
});
```

```html
<h3>Digite um valor e clique em alterar</h3>
<input id="input">
<button onclick="obj.item = document.getElementById('input').value">Alterar</button>
```

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#Browser_compatibility), a maioria dos browsers já suporta este recurso (com exceção do IE).